# Fastest way to find all direct subdirectories of a directory

Tags: java, performance, file, directory

Performance measurement showed that I spend a lot of time finding subdirectories. I use

```
File[] subDirArray = file.listFiles(new FileFilter()
{
  @Override
  public boolean accept(File pathname)
  {
    return pathname.isDirectory();
  }
});
```

to find all direct subdirectories of a given directory. Is there a way to do this faster (in Java 7)?

Comment: For what I know, this is the fastest way. Just you can make it multi thread for better performance

Comment: Any chance to cache the result and use a filewatcher to get informed about changes?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13539602/4448511