# Finder for folder name in a given path

Tags: java

I use java 1.7 and want to find every folder with a name beginning with "modRepart" in a given path. I 've found code to find files but not to find folders. I also find java 1.8 code that I can't use.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like that:

```
private static void findFolders(File[] files, String fileName, List<File> foundFiles) {
    for (File child : files) {
        if (child.isDirectory()) {
            if (child.getName().startsWith(fileName)) {
                foundFiles.add(child);
            }
            findFolders(child.listFiles(), fileName, foundFiles);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could modify [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13533527/6722100) existing answer, and just add in a `startsWith` clause:

```
File file = new File("C:\\path\\to\\wherever\\");
        String[] names = file.list();

        for (String name : names) {
            if (new File(file + "\\" + name).isDirectory() && name.startsWith("modRepart")) {
                System.out.println(name);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I'm using java 7, isn't the answer of Aksel Willgert better? I think java.nio.file is more powerfull.

Comment: This answer also uses `java.nio.file`